# Distribution of particles at infinite time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Let any site of $\mathbb{Z}$ host a number of particles $\eta_0(x)$ which is distributed according to some probability distribution independently and identically for any site $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. At time $0$ every particle starts an independent continuos-time random walk. Let $\eta_t(x)$ be the number of particles at $x$ at time $t$.

Does the process converges to a measure that is independent on the distribution of particles at time $0$?

I don't expect to receive a complete answer here, but where could I find an answer to this question?

Comment: Does it converge to a *distribution* that is independent of the distribution of particles at time $t = 0$?  That depends on the specific random walk.  Since you are talking about a continuous-time random walk, can you be more specific about what the process is, exactly?

Comment: Oh, and yes, this is a reasonably common topic of study.

Comment: I mean a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. Particles do not interact.

Comment: For a Markov process, if the system does not drift to infinity, then either the process has a stationary distribution and converges to it, or a process with an arbitrarily small additional diffusion term does so. (For instance, the discrete time Markov chain with transition matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ does not converge to its stationary distribution, but the chain with transition matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \delta & 1-\delta \\ 1-\delta & \delta \end{bmatrix}$ does, for small $\delta>0$.) This is "morally" correct, i.e. some technicalities may break it in some situations.

Comment: Does what you said hold automatically also if the space or realizations of the process is (countably) infinite?

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with one particle moving randomly at each time step with probability $\frac12$ to the left or to the right. The probability of having the particule at position $x$ at time $t$ follows the finite difference equation
$$p(x,t+1)=\frac12 p(x+1,t)+\frac12 p(x-1,t).\tag{1}$$
Let us solve this equation with initial condition $p(x,0)=1$ if $x=0$ and $p(x,0)=0$ otherwise. The solution is the binomial distribution 
$$p(2x,2t)=\frac1{2^{2t}}\binom {2t}{t+x}\qquad\qquad p(2x+1,2t+1)=\frac{1}{2^{2t+1}}\binom{2t+1}{t+x+1}.$$
It is known that for large $t$, this distribution converges to the Gaussian distribution such that 
$$p(x,t)\simeq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}\exp\left(-\frac{2x^2}{t}\right)$$

The general solution for the average number of particle at time $t$ and position $x$ is given by 
$$\overline{\eta}_t(x)=\sum_{y\in\mathbb Z}\eta_0(y)p(x-y,t).$$
The values $\eta_0(y)$ are fixed. For a large $t$, the Gaussian distribution
is large and therefore $p$ is relatively large on $[-\sqrt{t}, \sqrt{t}]$. This means that $\overline \eta_t(x)$ is the average of the values of $\eta_0(y)$ for $y\in[x-\sqrt{t},x+\sqrt{t}]$, which is, if it exists $\bar\eta$, the mean of the starting distribution. If the second order statistics of $\eta$ is defined, the fluctuations are of order $\frac{\sigma_\eta^2}{t}$ by the central limit theorem.

If the mean of $\eta$ does not exist, the convergence is not guaranteed globally.